# ¿Por qué mi programa no se detiene cuando le paso un 0?

Tags: java, hilos

Funciona casi bien, el único problema es que no se sale del programa al momento de pasar un 0
¿Alguien sabe por qué y como puedo arreglarlo?
He intentado cambiar algunas condiciones de los while, pero tampoco funciona
Incluso matar los hilos, pero igual no :c

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Carrera {
    private int premios;
    private boolean haTerminado;

    private class Competidor extends Thread {
        private String nombre;
        private Carrera carrera;
        private int premios;

        public Competidor(Carrera carrera, String nombre) {
            super("Hilo de " + nombre);
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.carrera = carrera;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (carrera.haTerminado() && premios < 5) {
                if (carrera.tomaPremio()) {
                    System.out.println(nombre + " obtuvo un premio.");
                    premios++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(nombre + " se retira, ganó " + premios + " premios");
        }
    }

    public boolean haTerminado() {
        return haTerminado;
    }

    public boolean hayPremios() {
        return premios > 0;
    }

    public synchronized boolean tomaPremio() {
        try {
            while (!haTerminado && !hayPremios()) {
                wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println(">>> Fue interrumpido: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return false;
        }
        premios--;
        return true;
    }

    public synchronized void agregaPremios(int premiosNuevos) {
        premios += premiosNuevos;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public void inicia(String[] nombres) {
        Competidor[] competidores = new Competidor[nombres.length];

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int opcion = -1;
        do {
            System.out.println("Ingresa la cantidad de premios nuevo o 0 para salir: ");
            try {
                opcion = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                System.out.println();
                for (int i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++) {
                    competidores[i] = new Competidor(this, nombres[i]);
                }
                if(opcion != 0){
                    for (Competidor competidor : competidores) {
                        competidor.start();
                        haTerminado = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    haTerminado = true;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("***Ingresa un número***\n");
            }
            if(opcion == 0){
                haTerminado = true;
            }
            if (opcion > 0) {
                agregaPremios(opcion);

            }

        } while (haTerminado != true);
        //haTerminado = false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Carrera ejemplo = new Carrera();
        String[] competidores = { "Pedro", "Juan", "Pablo", "Santiago", "Judas" };
        ejemplo.inicia(competidores);
    }
}
```

Comment: "no sale al momento de pasar un 0" ¿Qué no sale?

Comment: No se sale del programa*

Comment: ok, ahora al pasarle un cero en dónde? Como parámetro por línea de comandos?

Comment: As probado con el método equals en vez de comparar mediante == o !=?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo el gran problema de tu código es que nunca entra a tu ciclo while, que es lo que los que desarrollamos juegos le llamamos el ciclo de control principal.

debes cambiar la lógica de tu cilo para que diga

mientras la carrera no ha terminado y el competidor tenga menos de 5 premios
toma nu premio, es decir:

```
while (!carrera.haTerminado() && premiosDelCompetidor < 5) {
```

Ahora respecto a la ejecución.... como mejora te recomendaría meterle semáforos, si no simpre va a ganar le primero que crees